# How to give space between columns?

Tags: awk

I have a text file as shown below.I would like to give a space between the character and number in the fifth column. How can I do this with awk?

```
cxe  911  bv  heg   A1029   53.030
bvf  912  cv  lya   A1030   51.99

Desired output

cxe  911  bv  heg   A 1029   53.030
bvf  912  cv  lya   A 1030   51.99
```

Comment: Not awk: `sed 's/^.\{21\}/& /'`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}[^[:space:]]/) {
         print substr($0,1,RLENGTH), substr($0,RLENGTH+1) }' file
cxe  911  bv  heg   A 1029   53.030
bvf  912  cv  lya   A 1030   51.99
```

The "4" above is the number of columns before the one you're interested in, i.e. the 5th. If you want to operate on a different field, just change that number in the obvious way.

If you're using an older version of gawk you'd need to add the --re-interval flag but for newer gawks RE-intervals ({4}) are enabled by default.

Also, here's a briefer but GNU-awk specific solution if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}[^[:space:]])(.*)/,"\\1 \\3","")}' file
cxe  911  bv  heg   A 1029   53.030
bvf  912  cv  lya   A 1030   51.99
```

You can do similar in any awk using a pair of sub()s but it's ugly so I'd use the match()/substr() for those awks.

Finally if, as some others have posted, you want a solution to add a space after the 21st character on each line rather than after the first character in the 5th field on each line then that'd just be:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.{21}/,"& ")' file
cxe  911  bv  heg   A 1029   53.030
bvf  912  cv  lya   A 1030   51.99
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very specific to the format of your data, but it works:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,21)" "substr($0,22)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your fifth column starts with a single character,

```
{
  if(sub(/^./, "& ", $5)) {
    print $0;
  } 
}
```

Comment: The awk-ish way to write that would be `awk 'sub(/^./, "& ", $5)'` but in any case that would force awk to recompile the record turning all of the other chains of contiguous white space on the line (including the field separators) into single blank characters which almost certainly would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, But I guess this should work.

```
awk '{$5=substr($5,0,1)" "substr($5,1);print}' your_file
```

Comment: That would force awk to recompile the record turning all of the other chains of contiguous white space on the line (including the field separators) into single blank characters which almost certainly would be undesirable.