# giving space in the 5th column with awk

Tags: awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give space between columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898527/how-to-give-space-between-columns)

I have a PDB file as shown below. I would like to give a space in the 5th column.

```
ATOM   2614  CB  ALA B1130      -3.307 -21.676   3.322  1.00 15.69           C
ATOM   2615  N   LEU B1131      -4.584 -19.000   2.466  1.00 18.48           N
ATOM   2616  CA  LEU B1131      -4.847 -17.586   2.701  1.00 18.86           C
```

desired output

```
 ATOM   2614  CB  ALA B 1130      -3.307 -21.676   3.322  1.00 15.69           C
 ATOM   2615  N   LEU B 1131      -4.584 -19.000   2.466  1.00 18.48           N
 ATOM   2616  CA  LEU B 1131      -4.847 -17.586   2.701  1.00 18.86           C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require tab separated output, you could use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{ sub(/./, "& ", $5) }1' file
```

Results:

```
ATOM    2614    CB  ALA B 1130  -3.307  -21.676 3.322   1.00    15.69   C
ATOM    2615    N   LEU B 1131  -4.584  -19.000 2.466   1.00    18.48   N
ATOM    2616    CA  LEU B 1131  -4.847  -17.586 2.701   1.00    18.86   C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$5 = substr($5, 1, 1) " " substr($5, 2)' /tmp/foo.pdb
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have gawk:

```
awk '{$5=gensub(/^./,"& ","g",$5)}1' file
```